# Can a unit test perform double-duty by accepting a boolean value as a switch, or should I write two separate tests that duplicate the test code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, boolean, double

I have a method whose operations depend on its dependents, like below. Is it still value doing unit test? Because the unit test is not testing any business logic, rather by mocks.

Unit test below:

Please note that the method's opetions is determined by `expectedCustomerValidality`, which is setup by the test. Mostly, the logic is determined by mocks (e.g. `Setup(c => c.IsValid())`.

```
        [Test]
        [TestCase(true)]
        [TestCase(false)]
        public void AddCustomer(bool expectedCustomerValidality)
        {
           //using Moq
            companyRepositoryMock.Setup(c => c.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new Company());          
            customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => c.IsValid(It.IsAny<Customer>())).Returns(expectedCustomerValidality);

            var customer = new Customer
                               {
                                   Firstname = "firstName",
                                   Surname = "surname",
                                   Company = new Company { Id = 1 }
                               };

            var addCustomer = customerServiceSut.AddCustomer(customer);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedCustomerValidality,addCustomer);
        }
```

Production code below:

```
 public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
    {
        private ICompanyRepository companyRepository;
        private ICustomerRepository customerRepository;
        private ICustomerValidator customerValidator;

        public CustomerService(ICompanyRepository companyRepository, ICustomerRepository customerRepository, ICustomerValidator customerValidator)
        {
            this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
            this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
            this.customerValidator = customerValidator;

        }

        public bool AddCustomer(Customer customer)
        {           
            customer.Company = companyRepository.GetById(customer.Company.Id); ;

            if (customerValidator.IsValid(customer))
            {
                customerRepository.AddCustomer(customer);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
}
```

Questions:

- Is AddCustomer() required unit-testing?
- If so, is the current unit test performing the correct way?

  1 If not, what is the proper way to unit test it?

Comment: 1.  All methods containing non-trivial logic should be unit tested.  2.  What do you mean by "correct?"

Comment: 1. You meant the AddCustomer contains non-trivial logic. But it depends on its dependency, which is mocked. 2. In the test, the if branch is determined by the mock object.

Answer (score 7):

I don't like this.  Here's why: your test method names should reflect the method under test, what the preconditions of the test are, and what you expect the result of the test to be:

```
public bool AddCustomer_CustomerIsValid_ShouldReturnTrue()

public bool AddCustomer_CustomerIsInvalid_ShouldReturnFalse()
```

Now if you want to, you can refactor the core testing logic into its own method to eliminate the code duplication, and then call that method from the two above methods.  But the refactored method is not a test case; it's just a helper method for the actual test cases.

Example:

```
[Test]
public void AddCustomer_CustomerIsValid_ShouldReturnTrue()
{
    var result = AddCustomerTest(true);
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}

[Test]
public void AddCustomer_CustomerIsInvalid_ShouldReturnFalse()
{
    var result = AddCustomerTest(false);
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}

public void AddCustomerTest(bool expectedCustomerValidality)
{
   //using Moq
    companyRepositoryMock.Setup(c => c.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new Company());          
    customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => c.IsValid(It.IsAny<Customer>())).Returns(expectedCustomerValidality);

    var customer = new Customer
    {
        Firstname = "firstName",
        Surname = "surname",
        Company = new Company { Id = 1 }
    };

    var result= customerServiceSut.AddCustomer(customer);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this, any example?

Comment: @Pingpong: Your `AddCustomer(bool expectedCustomerValidality)` is no longer a test method.  Instead, it is the refactored method that the above two test methods call.  Return a bool in the refactored method, and assert that the return value is correct in each of the two test methods.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, but my original question is that, does the AddCustomer() method require unit testing considering its logic?

Comment: @Pingpong: That's all you wanted to know?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Please correct me if I am wrong. The AddCustomerTest() mostly uses mocks and does not test any business logic. Thus, it seems that AddCustomerTest() is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`AddCustomer` requires testing, as it performs a business logic - it retrieves a company, and sets it, it validates the data, it adds the data to the repository, and it returns a result.

Your test is almost correct. I would make it a little bit more specific, to verify all the business logic:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(true)]
[TestCase(false)]
public void AddCustomer(bool isCustomerValid)
{
     //arrange
     //NOTE!!! create the mocks with MockBehavior.Strict
     //that way the test will fail if a call is made w/o setup

     const long testCompanyId = 100;
     var testCompany = new Company{ Id = testCompanyId };
     companyRepository.Setup(r => r.GetById(testCompanyId))
          .Returns(testCompany);

     var testCustomer = new Customer
                   {
                        Firstname = "firstName",
                        Surname = "surname",
                        Company = new Company { Id = testCompanyId }
                   };

     customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => c.IsValid(It.Is<Customer>(c => c == testCustomer && c.Company == testCompany)).Returns(isCustomerValid);

     if (isCustomerValid)
     {
          customerRepository.Setup( r => r.AddCustomer(testCustomer) ). Verifiable();
     }

     //act        
     var addCustomerResult = customerServiceSut.AddCustomer(testCustomer);

     //assert
     Assert.AreEqual(isCustomerValid, addCustomerResult);
     cutomerRepository.VerifyAll();
}
```

The above test will test all the functionality of the service method, including if the company is fetched by id, and if the fetched one is used. Also, it will verify if the customer is added, if it is valid. The test will fail, if the customer is added if not valid (as the customerRepository is created with MockBehavior.Strict, and a setup will not be performed).